# How to get closest word to a reference word in purrr

Tags: r

I have a list as follows:

```
list(c("\n", "\n", "oesophagus graded  and fine\n", 
"\n", "\n", "\n", "stomach and  antrum  altough with some rfa response rfa\n", 
"\n", "mucosa washed a lot\n", "\n", "treated with halo rfa ultra \n", 
"\n", "total of 100 times\n", "\n", "duodenum looks ok"))
```

I'd like to extract from a list, the term that is closest to another term found in a different list.

My desired output is

```
antrum:rfa
```

My first list is:

```
EventList<-c("rfa", "apc", "dilat", "emr", "clip", "grasp", "probe", "iodine", 
"acetic", "nac", "peg", "botox")
```

My second list is:

```
tofind<-"ascending|descending|sigmoid|rectum|transverse|caecum|splenic|ileum|rectosigmoid|ileocaecal|hepatic|colon|terminal|terminal ileum|ileoanal|prepouch|pouch|stomach|antrum|duodenum|oesophagus|goj|ogj|cardia|anastomosis"
```

The code I am using is:

```
EventList %>%
        map(
          ~words %>%
            str_which(paste0('^.*', .x)) %>%
            map_chr(
              ~words[1:.x] %>%
                str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%

                str_extract_all(regex(tofind, ignore_case = TRUE)) %>%
                map_if(is_empty, ~ NA_character_) %>%
                flatten_chr()%>%
                `[[`(1) %>%

                .[length(.)]
            ) %>%
            paste0(':', .x)
        ) %>%
        unlist() %>%
        str_subset('.+:')
```

This gives me the Event (in this case `rfa`) but instead of allocating it to `antrum`, it allocates it to `oesophagus`.

It is therefore giving it to the first term found in the `tofind` list, rather than the term closest to the event.

I suspect the line

```
`[[`(1) %>%

 .[length(.)]
```

is the culprit but I don't know how to change it so that it gives me the closest term rather than the first term

Comment: I think the problem alread starts in the line for `words %>% str_which(paste0('^.*', .x)) `. Is the structure of your words-list bigger tan what you show? I mean, are there several vectors like the one you show, or is it really only a list of one vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you the last element matched in `tofind` for each matched element in the `EventList`

```
map(EventList, 
    function(event) {
      indices <- map(words, str_which, pattern = event)
      map(indices, function(i) 
        map2_chr(words, i, ~ .x[seq_len(.y)] %>% 
               str_c(collapse = ' ') %>% 
               str_extract_all(regex(tofind, ignore_case = TRUE), simplify = TRUE) %>% 
               last()) %>%
          map_if(is_empty, ~ NA_character_)
        ) %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        paste0(':', event)
    })  %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str_subset('.+:')

# [1] "antrum:rfa"     "oesophagus:rfa"
```